# Generalised formula for the given series

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

I have the below series :

`(1 * 0) + (2 * 1)  + (3 * 2) + (4 * 3) + ... + (n * (n-1))`

Is it possible to have a generalised formula for this.
Also such series like the above would be an AP(arithmetic progression) or GP(geometric progression) ?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note that there are [standard expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) for sums of the form $\sum_{k=1}^n k^p$ for natural numbers $p$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate as I am new to this. Just went through the link you shared and not sure how Faulhaber's formula would be applicable here

Comment: Your sum is $\sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k^2-k)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2-\sum_{k=1}^nk$.